# Storm: Could not update the blob with keyposTopology-1-1501640527-stormconf.ser

Tags: java, jdbc, redis, apache-storm

I'm building a storm topology includes jdbc and redis,
after runs few hours, showing blew msg:

```
[2017-08-02 17:37:59.917] ERROR [org.apache.storm.blobstore.BlobStoreUtils:197] - Could not update the blob with keypositionTopology-1-1501640527-stormconf.ser 
[2017-08-02 17:37:59.930] ERROR [org.apache.storm.blobstore.BlobStoreUtils:197] - Could not update the blob with keypositionTopology-1-1501640527-stormcode.ser
```

and then it show me this:

```
[2017-08-02 20:39:01.610] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn:1096] - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13374ms for sessionid 0x15da0c008310049, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
[2017-08-02 20:39:01.611] WARN  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn:357] - caught end of stream exception:
org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15da0c008310049, likely client has closed socket
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141] 
[2017-08-02 20:39:01.614] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn:1007] - Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62631 which had sessionid 0x15da0c008310048
[2017-08-02 20:39:01.711] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager:228] - State change: SUSPENDED
[2017-08-02 20:39:01.711] WARN  [org.apache.storm.cluster-state.zookeeper-state-factory:  0] - Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Writer Zookeeper.
[2017-08-02 20:39:01.713] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager:228] - State change: SUSPENDED
[2017-08-02 20:39:01.713] WARN  [org.apache.storm.cluster-state.zookeeper-state-factory:  0] - Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Writer Zookeeper.
[2017-08-02 20:39:01.713] INFO  [org.apache.storm.zookeeper:  0] - Zookeeper state update: :disconnected:none
[2017-08-02 20:39:01.713] INFO  [org.apache.storm.zookeeper:  0] - debian lost leadership.
```

and this shift...

```
[2017-08-02 20:59:30.930] WARN  [org.apache.storm.kafka.PartitionManager:218] - Removing the failed offsets for Partition{host=10.2.5.207:9092, topic=grih_pos, partition=0} that are out of range: [1786800768, 1786800769, 1786800770, 1786800771, 1786800772, 1786800773, 1786800774, 1786800775, 1786800776, 1786800777, 1786800778, 1786800779, 1786800780, 1786800781, 1786800782, 1786800783, 1786800784, 1786800785, 1786800786, 1786800787, 1786800788, 1786800789, 1786800790, 1786800791, 1786800792, 1786800793, 1786800794, 1786800795, 1786800796, 1786800797, 1786800798, 1786800799, 1786800800, 1786800801, 1786800802, 1786800803, 1786800804, 1786800805, 1786800806, 1786800807, 1786800808, 1786800809, 1786800810, 1786800811, 1786800812, 1786800813, 1786800814, 1786800815, 1786800816, 1786800817, 1786800818, 1786800819, 1786800820, 1786800821, 1786800822, 1786800823, 1786800824, 1786800825, 1786800826, 1786800827, 1786800828, 1786800829, 1786800830, 1786800831, 1786800832, 1786800833, 1786800834, 1786800835, 1786800836, 1786800837, blablabla...
```

finally OOM:

```
[2017-08-02 22:30:16.311] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn:512] - EventThread shut down
[2017-08-02 22:30:16.311] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper:438] - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2000/storm sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@58f254b1
[2017-08-02 22:30:16.309] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper:438] - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2000/storm sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@437ed416
[2017-08-02 22:30:21.338] WARN  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState:191] - Connection attempt unsuccessful after 25460 (greater than max timeout of 20000). Resetting connection and trying again with a new connection.
[2017-08-02 22:30:21.341] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn:975] - Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[2017-08-02 22:30:21.338] ERROR [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState:200] - Connection timed out for connection string (localhost:2000) and timeout (15000) / elapsed (15162)
org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:197) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:88) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:116) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:835) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:809) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:64) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:267) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]
[2017-08-02 22:30:21.342] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn:852] - Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000, initiating session
[2017-08-02 22:30:28.864] WARN  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState:191] - Connection attempt unsuccessful after 32985 (greater than max timeout of 20000). Resetting connection and trying again with a new connection.
[2017-08-02 22:30:41.625] INFO  [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn:975] - Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[2017-08-02 22:30:41.631] ERROR [org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl:566] - Background exception was not retry-able or retry gave up
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1969) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.Package.getPackage(Package.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.Class.getPackage(Class.java:796) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.toCacheEntry(ThrowableProxy.java:495) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.toExtendedStackTrace(ThrowableProxy.java:547) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:113) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:323) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:64) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:36) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:197) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:55) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout.toByteArray(AbstractStringLayout.java:67) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:108) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:88) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:99) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:430) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:409) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:367) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:112) ~[log4j-core-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:727) ~[log4j-api-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:716) ~[log4j-api-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.error(Log4jLogger.java:318) ~[log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:200) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:88) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:116) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:835) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:809) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:64) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:267) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
```

I just set 2 bolt in this topology, one for jdbc and another for redis, 
And the spout is KafkaSpout, consuming the data from Kafka.

this issue nagged at me 4 A LONG TIME,
I Google it over and over,
and got no shift..

Desiring for your help!